# Flickering when I scroll Table

Tags: jquery, html

I have tried to do fixed scroll header. In this process, trying to fix the HEAD table position fixed. I did it. But, when I scroll the table, HEAD table is flickering. Its not flickering in Firefox. I don't want to have this flickering in IE, Chrome or any browser. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**CSS CODE:**

```
<style type="text/css">
th {
    background:#663300;
    color:#FFF;}
</style>
```

**JQUERY CODE**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mainDiv").scroll(function() {
                var offSet = $("#mainDiv").offset().top;
                $("#headTable").offset({"top":offSet});
            });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML CODE (FULL PAGE CODE)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
th {
    background:#663300;
    color:#FFF;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mainDiv").scroll(function() {
                var offSet = $("#mainDiv").offset().top;
                $("#headTable").offset({"top":offSet});
            });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p style="height:100px;">&nbsp;</p>
<div id="mainDiv" style="border:1px solid red; width:400px; height:100px; overflow:auto; position:relative;">
    <table id="headTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="z-index:10;">
        <tr>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="bodyTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="z-index:9;">
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you running this in?

Answer (score 0):

Because onscroll is slow and does not give the precision you need to make it smooth. There is no need to set the header with onscroll, CSS position the header table on top of the scrollable div.